# What's the maximum a silo can store?

Tags: farming-simulator-2013

I wonder if the silos in farming simulator 2013 have a maximum capacity? There is no hint how much they can store, but I just can't imagine that they have endless space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default map doesn't have a limit and silos hold infinite amounts, I believe.  However there is a slow decay factor that might be active, so you don't want to store too much otherwise you're slowly losing the materials to decay.

Note: It should be noted that some mod maps place limits on these silos and also there are ways to change the limitations using something called Giants Editor.  If you use this it basically gives you access to options that some might call configuration options which shows that the option for silos is blank thus making it infinite, and in turn also letting you give it a limit.