# What is the silo decay rate?

Tags: farming-simulator-2013

According to [What's the maximum a silo can store?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114320/whats-the-maximum-a-silo-can-store), silos have a decay rate proportional to the amount of grains stored in the silo. Can anyone give us exact numbers on this decay?